# Determine whether sequence is non-decreasing or increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence, where $n \in \mathbb N$ $$1-{1\over 3^n}$$
I'm supposed to determine whether the sequence is **non-decreasing**.

Knowing that for a **non-decreasing** sequence
$$a_n \le a_{n+1}$$

I'm not sure if my solution is correct
$$1-{1\over 3^n} \le 1-{1\over 3^{n+1}}$$
$$1-{1\over 3^n} \le 1-{1\over 3^{n}\cdot3}$$
$$-{1\over 3^n} \le -{1\over 3^{n}\cdot3}$$
$$-3^n\cdot3 \le -3^n$$
$$3 \ge 1$$
Does this prove the sequence is **non-decreasing**? If not, how can it be determined?

EDIT:
If I try to prove the sequence is **strictly increasing** ($a_n \lt a_{n+1}$)
$$1-{1\over 3^n} \lt 1-{1\over 3^{n+1}}$$
$$1-{1\over 3^n} \lt 1-{1\over 3^{n}\cdot3}$$
$$-{1\over 3^n} \lt -{1\over 3^{n}\cdot3}$$
$$-3^n\cdot3 \lt -3^n$$
$$3 \gt 1$$
I am a little confused, since this also proves the sequence is **strictly increasing**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does prove the result.

Comment: Some readers might prefer you to start with what you know and work down to the result you want to prove, i.e. reversing the order of your lines.  Essentially what you are saying is that $3^n$ is an increasing function of $n$ so $\frac{1}{3^n}$ is a decreasing function of $n$ so $1-\frac{1}{3^n}$ is an increasing function of $n$

Comment: You can use one of two statements to directly find if a sequence is (decreasing) monotonic: the one you used,  $a_n \le a_{n+1}$ or $0 < \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le 1$. For exponential sequences, like the one of your question, the best option is the second statement. But you can use the first one as well, so your approach is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What you may also attempt could is called [Mathematical Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). **Proof by induction requires 2 things**:

- Proving that the property $a_n\leq a_{n+1}$ holds for the base case (in this case, $n=1$).
- Proving that the property $a_n\leq a_{n+1}$ holds for any relevant $n$ (in this case, $n\in\mathbb N$).

$a_1 = 1-\frac{1}{3^1} = \frac{2}{3} = \frac{6}{9}$

$a_2 = 1-\frac{1}{3^2} = \frac{8}{9}$

Thus we conclude that $a_1\leq a_2$.

Adding this to your proof that $a_n\leq a_{n+1}$ for any $n\in\mathbb N$, we've proven the the sequence is non-decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Since “adding $1$” is an increasing operation, you can simply look at the sequence $(-1/3^n)$. This is increasing if and only if the sequence $(1/3^n)$ is decreasing, which is equivalent to $(3^n)$ being increasing, which is true.

Your idea is good as well: in the display below, each line is equivalent to the previous one:
\begin{gather}
1-\frac{1}{3^n}< 1-\frac{1}{3^{n+1}} \\
-\frac{1}{3^n} < -\frac{1}{3^{n+1}} \\
\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}< \frac{1}{3^n} \\
\frac{1}{3} < 1
\end{gather}
Since the last line is a true statement, also the first line is.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant proof can be achieved with a little bit of calculus;

Let $f(n) = 1 - \frac{1} {3^n}$. Then $f'(n) = \frac{1}{3^n}\log(3)$.

Note that $a = \log(3) = 1.099 > 0$, and that for any $n$, $b = \frac{1}{3^n} > 0$.

Thus, $f(n) = 1 - \frac{1} {3^n} = ab > 0$, which means that $f(n)$ is **monotonically increasing**, and so it is **non-decreasing**.

Comment: You have picked a differentiable function $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{3^x}$ that happens to coincide with the given sequence when $x\in \mathbb{N}$. But what if $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{3^x} + \sin(\pi x)$ ? This also coincides with the sequence when $x \in \mathbb{N}$ but it is not non-decreasing.

Comment: @gandalf61 That's a very good point. Does that mean this answer is plain wrong, or does it need a little bit more work to be right?

Comment: I think you can rescue the proof by arguing that as long as you can find *one* non-decreasing differentiable function that matches the sequence on $\mathbb{N}$ then the sequence itself is non-decreasing. But you have to import a lot of infrastructure from calculus to replace a very simple proof based on the sequence alone.